# use same function for controls that implement ienumerable of object

Tags: .net, winforms, combobox, listbox, ienumerable

i have this function that i want to use for listbox, kryptonlistbox, combobox, kryptoncombobox, toolstripcombobox

```
 Friend Sub RefreshFromOption(ByRef cbo As KryptonComboBox, ByVal key As String)
        Try
            If Not dicOptions.ContainsKey(key) Then Exit Sub
            cbo.Items.Clear()
            cbo.Items.AddRange(dicOptions(key).Split(","))
        Catch ex As Exception
            LogError(ex)
        End Try

        If cbo.Items.Count > 0 Then cbo.SelectedIndex = 0 'cboReligion.FindStringExact("Default")
    End Sub
```

currently i have to write the same function for all 5 winform component, but is there a way to use one function for all.

i researchec the ienumerable interface, but didnt get anything to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the controls have their own `Object.Collection` for the `Items` property internally defined, you have to use those as parameters to update them seperately like this:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private readonly IDictionary<string , string> _dictionary;
        private readonly ComboBox _comboBox;
        private readonly ToolStripComboBox _toolStripComboBox;
        private readonly ListBox _listBox;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _comboBox = new ComboBox();
            _toolStripComboBox = new ToolStripComboBox();
            _listBox = new ListBox();

            _dictionary = new Dictionary<string , string>();

            UpdateControls( 
                "test" , 
                new ListControl[] { _comboBox , _toolStripComboBox.ComboBox , _listBox } ,
                new IList[] { _comboBox.Items , _toolStripComboBox.Items , _listBox.Items } );
        }

        private void UpdateControls( string key , IEnumerable<ListControl> listControls , IEnumerable<IList> itemCollections )
        {
            var items = GetItems( key ).ToArray();
            if ( items.Length > 0 )
            {
                UpdateItemsCollection( items , itemCollections );
                UpdateSelectedIndex( listControls );
            }
        }

        private static void UpdateSelectedIndex( IEnumerable<ListControl> listControls )
        {
            foreach ( var listControl in listControls )
            {
                listControl.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }

        private static void UpdateItemsCollection( object[] objects , IEnumerable<IList> objectCollections )
        {
            foreach ( var objectCollection in objectCollections )
            {
                objectCollection.Clear();
                foreach ( var obj in objects )
                {
                    objectCollection.Add( obj );
                }
            }
        }

        private IEnumerable<object> GetItems( string key )
        {
            if ( _dictionary.ContainsKey( key ) )
            {
                return _dictionary[key].Split( ',' );
            }
            return null;
        }
```